# Can free email provider's partners and affiliates read your emails?

Tags: email, privacy

I read that if you use free email, these entities have access to your very personal info!:

"Your email provider company itself, like Google

Their partners and affiliates

Your ISP

Various government agencies, from the NSA to the FBI

They don’t just store what’s in your emails and who’s sending and receiving them, but information like IP address, location, common topics you talk about, your interests, your clicks, and more."

I get that the Email provider and government have such access, but the partners and affiliates and ISP - can they read your emails if they decide to want to? So, for examle, if a stalker asks someone working at any of those companies to look me up and read my emails and find out my IP, CAN THEY technically DO THAT?

Comment: Of course it is technically possible. Email is not a secure communication channel. That's why encryption of messages is  such a big thing.

Comment: In theory they can also edit your emails, and create valid looking replies.

Comment: ok so its technically and in theory possible - that sounds like a totally awful privacy breach :((((. Can this "realistically" happen, though? What are the hurdles? Does the bad spy have to be a good hacker or something? I don't want certain people to find out what I'm up to or what my IP is by reading emails that I thought were private between me and the recipient/sender!!!!! >_<

Comment: the best protection against mass surveillance is cryptography and encryption.

Comment: @norrrr You have to define what you want to protect yourself against. You keep changing who the threat is. Can someone ask an employee of Google to read your email for them? Sure - that can certainly be done. Can someone do that and not get *caught*? That's another story entirely. I think you need to more properly define what you concerns are.

Answer (score 2):

Sure they can but reputable providers typically don't. [Google's Terms of Use](https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/#nosharing) are pretty specific about sharing. They'll share your info

1. When you opt-in to something (eg: a purchase).
2. With your admin if you are using a Google Apps domain.
3. With a Google affiliate (ie: a different Google company).
4. When required to by law. In the US this is likely a warrant.

So the FBI and the NSA can get warrants, but hopefully you're boring as far as they're concerned. I wouldn't recommend conducting illegal business without strong email encryption (and VPN and ...).

So affiliates "yes" but partners "no".

They do sell advertising but that is something like "We have a 19 year-old male reading an email about customizing transmissions for a Ferrari. How much will you pay to put an ad on their page."

One thing to keep in mind is that they absolutely don't want to give personally identifiable information about you to their advertisers as then the advertisers can market directly to you.

Oh. And this isn't specific to a free email account. Any email provider can do this. Read the terms of service.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, anyone who stores data unencrypted on your behalf can read it. This is the simple physics of information, and there's no way around it. If you don't want it to be read, you encrypt it and don't give away the key. That's literally your only option.

As for what *does* happen, the larger and more established the company, the better their technical controls are and the less likely they are to intentionally or unintentionally do anything that may be considered by the courts to be a violation of user trust or privacy.

If an individual hosts your email on their own personal server, then reading your email is as simple as opening a file. If instead your email is hosted by a multi-billion-dollar company, then reading your email likely requires written justification, explicit approval by legal counsel, and a traceable record in the audit logs, all with the expectation that the whole history may be presented in court.

We have a few examples from the news to draw from:

- [Microsoft recently pledged](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2014/03/microsoft-will-no-longer-look-through-your-hotmail-to-investigate-leaks/) to stop reading private email to investigate leaks without also involving law enforcement.
- Hushmail (a Canadian company advertised that "not even a Hushmail employee with access to our servers can read your encrypted e-mail") [famously trojaned their own web UI](http://www.wired.com/2007/11/encrypted-e-mai/) to make it possible to collect unencrypted email and turn it over to the US government.